# What type of a test will I perform in R?

Tags: biostatistics

I have a dataset which contains data observed for patients who were hospitalized for moderate or severe infection and given one of two antibiotics. The number of days each patient was hospitalized before discharge was also noted down. The analysis is divided into 2 parts;

Part 1: I have to compute if there is a significant difference between the average days of hospitalization on the two antibiotics.

Part 2: I have to compute if there is a significant difference between average days of hospitalization on the two antibiotics, after adjusting for age and severity of infection

A sample from the dataset is given below.

```
> head(antibiotic)

     trt age Infection.Severity Male Days.Hospitalized

1 Old Ab 41 severe 1 22

2 Old Ab 56 moderate 0 2

3 Old Ab 56 severe 1 15

4 Old Ab 66 moderate 1 15

5 Old Ab 45 moderate 1 3

6 Old Ab 41 severe 0 19
```

**My question is, what type of a test can I use for this analysis?**

Note that the treatment and infection severity data is not numerical.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to account for variable age and sex, then there are two possibilities:

1. If any data are censored (that is, some patients are still in the hospital) then I suggest survival analysis.
2. If not, then you want some form of regression. Since "days" is an integer, you might want to use a count regression model such as Poisson or negative binomial regression. This is especially true if most of the LOS are fairly small numbers. If LOS covers a wide range of numbers, then the "regular" OLS regression might be OK - but carefully check the assumptions. OLS regression technically requires a continuous dependent variable, but if the integers vary a lot, then this usually isn't problematic.\

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you so much for getting back to me. I do not have any censored data so Kaplan Mieir won't really be useful right?

Comment: The analysis is divided into two parts;

Part 1: I have to compute if there is a significant difference between average days of hospitalization on the two antibiotics.

Part 2: I have to compute if there is a significant difference between average days of hospitalization on the two antibiotics, after adjusting for age and severity of infection

That's why I was thinking about using regression analysis myself, but in the course I am taking right now, we have only covered linear, multiple, and logistic regression. I think part 1 will be linear and part 2 will be multiple regression then?

Comment: Do you have any other thoughts?

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @saintacacia if you know about linear and logistic then moving to Poisson or negative binomial should not be a big leap and as Peter suggests it would be a superior approach. You might edit the content of your comments into the question as well.

Comment: Well, you can *try* simple and multiple linear regression,but I think that is likely that you will violate the assumptions. I'm not sure how much I agree with @mdewey , I think it can be a pretty big jump from OLS regression to Poisson and NB. You might want to hire a consultant.

Comment: Thanks @mdewey and Peter for your inputs. I am still confused about how I can use any test with the treatment data not being numeric. I guess I can go the logistic way and assign 0 for one treatment and 1 for another?

Comment: Well, I ended up doing the Chi-sq test and got an error message. Did get a p-value but with the error message so I don't know where to go next

days <- with(antibiotic,table(Days.Hospitalized, trt))
chisq.test(days)

Pearson's Chi-squared test
data: days
X-squared = 51.381, df = 31, p-value = 0.01214

Warning message:
In chisq.test(days) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

Comment: Just thought about this but this be an ANOVA analysis?